# Boost.Log asynchronous logging invoke flush() periodically

Tags: c++, asynchronous, logging, boost, boost-asio

I am implementing a wrapper on top of Boost.Log. in Asynchronous logging, the logger doesn't write the log message immediately and makes a queue of messages. when calling the `core.get()->flush()` method, messages will be written to file.

But obviously it is not efficient to invoke flush() after each message. And in that way async logging has no benefit. And also it is not a good idea to invoke it once at the end of the program. (maybe the program is running on server for a long time)

I want to write a code to invoke flush() periodicaly (e.g. every 10 ms).

With this [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer3.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928020/using-boostasiodeadline-timer-inside-a-thread?rq=1) question, I wrote a asynchronous timer using Boost.asio, but it didn't write messages to file. Actually logger doesn't create any .log file. maybe because of flush() method must be invoked when no logging is occured.

```
typedef sinks::asynchronous_sink<
    sinks::text_file_backend,
    sinks::unbounded_ordering_queue<
        logging::attribute_value_ordering< unsigned int, std::less< unsigned int > >
    >
> Async_file_sink;

void do_flush(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/,
    boost::asio::deadline_timer* t)
{
    logging::core::get()->flush();

    t->expires_at(t->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));
    t->async_wait(boost::bind(do_flush,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error, t));
}

struct PerodicTimer{
    PerodicTimer(boost::asio::deadline_timer &timer) : t(timer) {
        t.async_wait(boost::bind(do_flush,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error, &t));
   }
   boost::asio::deadline_timer& t;
};

void init_flushing()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));

    PerodicTimer m(t);
        std::thread th([&]{
        // std::cout << "inside thread" << std::endl;
        io.run();
    });

    th.detach();
}

static void init_logging() 
{
    logging::add_common_attributes();
    boost::shared_ptr< Async_file_sink > sink(new Async_file_sink(
        boost::make_shared< sinks::text_file_backend >(),
        keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 1024 * 1024,
        // We'll apply record ordering to ensure that records from different threads go sequentially in the file
        keywords::order = logging::make_attr_ordering("LineID", std::less< unsigned int >())
    ));

    // Set up where the rotated files will be stored
    init_file_collecting(sink);
    sink->set_formatter(&my_formatter);
    sink->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
    init_flushing();  // Starting Timer
} 

int main()
{
    init_logging();

    ADD_LOG("SOME MESSAGE");
}
```

I think the problem is when flush() is being invoked(), at the same time asynch logger is logging messages. I cannot run asynch timer in the same thread, because io.run() is blocking.

what is a minimal solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `init_flushing`, you immediately exit after spawning a thread and destroy both `io_service io` and `deadline_timer t` objects while the thread is running. This is undefined behavior, so that could explain why the code is not behaving as you expect.

Both `io` and `t` must stay alive while the thread is running. But, since you're not using `io` for anything else but waiting for the timer, it would be much simpler to just have a loop that calls `std::this_thread::sleep_for` to wait and an atomic flag to terminate the loop.

```
std::thread flushing_thread;
std::atomic<bool> terminate_flushing_thread{ false };

void init_flushing()
{
    assert(!flushing_thread.joinable());

    flushing_thread = std::thread([]()
    {
        while (!terminate_flushing_thread.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            logging::core::get()->flush();
        }
    });
}

void stop_flushing()
{
    if (flushing_thread.joinable())
    {
        terminate_flushing_thread.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        flushing_thread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working. I think you mean `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` ?

Comment: Also it sounds calling `core::flush()` is necessary after while loop inside `flushing_thread`. because maybe by invoking `stop_flushing()` still some log messages are not sent to file.

Comment: > I think you mean `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` ? -- Right, I've corrected the answer.

Comment: > Also it sounds calling core::flush() is necessary after while loop inside flushing_thread. because maybe by invoking stop_flushing() still some log messages are not sent to file. -- Not really. You're not supposed to call `stop_flushing` while your application is still running and can generate log records. When it is called, you're shutting down. Also, `flushing_thread` calls `flush` just before exiting, unless you terminate it immediately after spawning.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here. I just started playing with async frontends so I'd really like to understand. What is the point of a flush that runs in another thread like this constantly? When in flush, all sinks block. If every 10ms your async sink will be in a state where it blocks on any logging until all outstanding log records are flushed, what is the point of having it be async? I must be misunderstanding something...

Comment: @aggieNick02 Yes, flushing with async sinks is inherently more expensive, as it has to synchronize multiple threads. You should be asking the author of the question as to what his use case is and why he needs this. Explicit flushing ensures that any buffered records are processed. In particular, this means that in case of a crash you are less likely to lose buffered records. Whether you need that guarantee is up to you. You may be fine with the `auto_flush` functionality in the sink backends.